# JavaScript reorder object properties given an array of properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a javascript object like:

```
{
  a: 3,
  b: 10,
  c: 2,
  d: 7,
}
```

I have an array containing string representations of the property names:

```
[ "c", "b", "a", "d" ]
```

How do I rearrange my object so that the properties are arranged in the same order as in the array, eg:

```
{
  c: 2,
  b: 10,
  a: 3,
  d: 7,
}
```

Comment: The order of properties in an Object is arbitrary. What is the actual goal here?

Comment: You have to construct a new object and add the properties in the order you want. However I would strongly suggest you re-think the coding strategy that relies on object property ordering, because it will make your code extremely fragile.

Comment: Can you sort the array to match the object property order?

Comment: why not take the array as an ordered accessor?

Comment: This really seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is your actual use case?

Comment: @ChrisG—not entirely, see [*Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although ECMAScript-6 improved the feature, object properties are still notoriously unordered. A way to fix this would be to use a Map which remembers the original key insertion order.

```js
    const obj = { a: 3, b: 10, c: 2, d: 7 };
const arr = ["c", "b", "a", "d"];

const res = new Map(arr.map(e => [e, obj[e]]));

for (let [key, value] of [...res]) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

<sub>(The `for...of` loop is just to show the actual Map, as they aren't shown on the Stack Snippets console.)</sub>